# Query using sequelizejs returns undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sequelize.js

A model.js file contains this model :

```
exports.Conversations = db.sequelize.define('conversations', {
room_id: {        
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
},                        
user_id: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
},
friend_id: {
    type: db.Sequelize.STRING
},
},  {
timestamps: true,
createdAt:'created_at',
updatedAt:'updated_at',
deletedAt:'deleted_at',
freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
});
```

In query.js I have the following function :

```
exports.checkRoom = function(user_id,friend_id) {
models.Conversations.findOne({ where: { $or: [{user_id: user_id , friend_id: friend_id}, {user_id: friend_id , friend_id: user_id}]  }} ).then(function(conversation) {
   return conversation;
});
}
```

equivalent to:

```
SELECT 
    "id", "room_id", "user_id", "friend_id", "created_at", "updated_at" 
FROM  
    "conversations" AS "conversations" 
WHERE 
    (("conversations"."user_id" = '127' AND "conversations"."friend_id" = '124') 
     OR ("conversations"."user_id" = '124' AND "conversations"."friend_id" = '127')) 
LIMIT 1;
```

When I do a call on that function in my cluster.js

```
var conversation = query.checkRoom(data.userId,data.friendId));
```

I get that conversation is undefined.

Found a couple of solutions to catch the object Promise but didnt worked.

Looking forward to your answers.

EDIT

Managed to do that but when calling the query I want to add that answer to a var so I can use it later on. If now i`m doing something like var

```
conversationId = query.checkRoom(data.userId, data.friendId).then(function(conversation) { return conversation.dataValues.id; })
```

I get that my var conversationId is [object Promise] .

How can I get and use that Promise outside .then() function ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `checkRoom()` as a synchronous function, which it isn't (like most functions dealing with I/O in Node).

Instead, you should return the promise returned by `findOne()` and handle the resolving (and rejection) of that promise in your calling code:

```
// query.js
exports.checkRoom = function(user_id, friend_id) {
  return models.Conversations.findOne({ where: { $or: [{user_id: user_id , friend_id: friend_id}, {user_id: friend_id , friend_id: user_id}]  }} );
}

// calling code
query.checkRoom(data.userId, data.friendId).then(function(conversation) {
  // do something with the database result
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Managed to do that but when calling the query I want to add that answer to a var so I can use it later on.
If now i`m doing something like 

    var conversationId = query.checkRoom(data.userId, data.friendId).then(function(conversation) {
return conversation.dataValues.id;
})

I get that my var conversationId is [object Promise]

Comment: @Edu you can't return scalar values like that from asynchronous callbacks, even if those callbacks are used as a promise resolve handler.

Comment: What turnaround would you think of and suggest in this case?

Comment: @Edu I don't know your particular use case so it's difficult to give a general solution :-(

Comment: Basically I need to return just the ID of my query object. Couldn’t I just return it as a string or something inside .then() ?

Comment: @Edu no, that's not how asynchronous code works. A solution depends on how you subsequently need to use that id (or the conversation object).

Comment: I`m using that ID just to verify a user connection to a conversation (Socket.io - Laravel), basicaly just one time on a connect event.

Comment: @Edu so basically, you want to allow messages from a user only if they are confirmed to be part of a particular conversation? If so, you can set up the message listeners for socket.io _inside_ the `then` callback.

Comment: Worked! Initially I thought that inside then the socket will not me accessible.
Thank you so much for your support! Keep up the good work